# How to import CreateDataBinding into Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am new to MVVMCross concept and Hybride development.
In my project I have a .xml file with a UI-Component that has a listener attribute "o'clock" for example.

I want to bind the o'clock to the ViewModel. I check some posts in the internet and I found the one shown below.

The question is, how can I import or have access to:

```
CreateBindingSet and DelayBind
```

into the project because I do not have access to it.

**code**:

```
this.DelayBind(() => {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<KittenCollectionCell, 
Kitten>();
            set.Bind(NameLabel).To(kitten => kitten.Name);
            set.Bind (PriceLabel).To (kitten => kitten.Price);
            set.Bind (_loader).To (kitten => kitten.ImageUrl);
            set.Bind(MyAwesomeButton).To(vm => vm.MyAwesomeCommand);
            set.Apply();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `CreateBindingSet` and `DelayBind` are extension methods living in namespace `MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext`. 
In order to use them, add a using statement like so on top of you file:

```
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
```